# Rails: Why is etag not available in before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, http-caching

**I am trying to add a use [`etag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet/ClassMethods.html) to add a ETag with the current users ID:**

```
UsersController:Class < ApplicationController 
  etag { current_user.id } if user_signed_in?
end
```

However this fails since the Devise helpers are not available when the controller class is defined:

`` undefined method `user_signed_in?' ``

**If I attempt to use `etag` in a `before_action` it is not defined:**

```
before_action do
 etag { current_user.try(:id) } if user_signed_in? # undefined method `etag'
end
```

**I have also tried:**

```
before_action do
  self.etag { current_user.id } if user_signed_in? 
end
```

Which does not seem to add an extra `etagger`.

Comment: why not something like etag {current_user.id} if current_user

Comment: @user3334690 `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`

Comment: if defined?(current_user)  maybe? or possibly unless self.try(:current_user).nil? ... we don't use devise so I'm not exactly sure the scope current_user is defined as...

Comment: Because if its in a scope where Devise is not yet initialized it will always be nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you first example `self` is the class itself, so while the `etag` method is defined, `user_signed_in` isn't. Rails ignores any etag block that returns nil you could instead do

```
etag { current_user.id if user_signed_in? }
```

or simply

```
etag { current_user.try :id}
```

Your second and third examples don't work because rails uses `instance_exec` to evaluate the block, so `self` is an instance of the class on which you cannot call class methods.

Lastly, I can't tell from what you've posted whether you're already aware of this, but the etaggers added with `etag` are only used if you call `fresh_when`.

Comment: Works perfectly, so `user_signed_in?` is defined in the block because it is called with an instance of the controller as a the context?